# What is the use of apk scope in gradle-android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The documentation describes apk scope as package time only dependency, so it won't be used for compilation.

I cannot think of any scenario where I need something at runtime, but not needed for compilation. If I use a jar (not a library project .aar, just a library), my code will definitely have references to the library - and if the library is not found during compilation, I cannot test on a device to check for runtime availability of library.

PS: I understand 'apk' scope is the same as 'package' scope for non-android projects. It would help even if someone can explain from a non-android perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a jar contains com.library.A,
you can use class A by

```
try{
   Object o = Class.forName("com.library.A").newInstance().
   if(o!=null){
   }
}catch(Throwable e){
}
```

You don't need to have it in compilation.

So you can build project faster.When you generate an apk,you can use the library as normal.

Comment: Doesn't this bit `A a =` require you to resolve A, and hence need package containing A during compile?

Comment: Shoudln't it be `Object o = Class.forName("com.library.A").newInstance()`

Comment: and then how can I use the methods of A? since I can't cast the instance o to A...