# Newly Created Android Library module conflicts with Icon and Versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I created an android library module and hosted it on my Github. However, the library conflicts with Icons and Versions of Android Studio projects. When appended to the gradle of my Android project, the following errors are displayed:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.

and

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-45
>       is also present at [com.github.dinukapj:ATM-EditText:1.2] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-43 value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-305:19 to override.

I understand that by adding `tools:replace="android:value"` and `tools:replace="android:icon"` to the manifest's application tag will fix this, but since it's a library I don't want to force developers to do this for every project.

My library: https://github.com/dinukapj/ATM-EditText/

Is there a way to resolve this conflict from my library project?

Comment: You are using the lib project sdk version 25 and the main project version is 26 so it is conflicting each other. Try to change the version of main project with 25 this will resolve your issue.

Comment: That resolved it. Thank you. Please add that as an answer :) @AndyDeveloper

Comment: welcome sir :) I add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way of dealing with framework compatibility issues in library modules is to *compile your library against a given version* (in your case Support Lib v25) but *do not include the  library* in the compiled output.

---

Normally the `dependencies` would include:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

This line does 3 things:

- it allows your code to use classes and methods in that library
- it *compiles* those classes and methods into the library output AAR file
- this means that anyone using your library has access to them without declaring them in the app's build.gradle file

The second point is where conflicts can come in.

---

My preferred way is to include the external `dependencies` into the library module using the `provided` keyword like this:

```
provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

This is slightly different to the above:

- it allows your code to use the classes and methods (as above)
- it *does not compile* the classes into the library output AAR file
- it tells the library's user/developer that the classes must be *provided* in the app's build gradle file
- this means that anyone using your library does not have access to the classes without adding the dependency themselves in the app's build.gradle

The nice part of this is that the developer using your library can depend on any (compatible) version of the external framework they want, e.g. in your case they would include the following in their app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

---

Some extra links:

- [Android Developer docs on Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)
- [Gradle Dependencies difference...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947897/gradle-dependencies-difference-between-compile-apk-project-compile-project-pro)
- [Android Dependency scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472785/compile-provided-apk-android-dependency-scope)

---

This technique is best suited to libraries that are highly likely to be included in the app in any case e.g. Android Support libs, GSON, etc

To summarise:

- we build the library against 1 version
- the user must provide the dependency in their project

Your users are then free to use whichever library version they want.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer my gosh, loved all the new things I learned from it. I accepted it as the answer. Thanks again Richard!

Comment: I'm glad it could help. The timing of your question could not have been better as I have been working on exactly this issue very recently.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the lib project SDK version 25 and the main project version is 26 so it is conflicting each other. Try to change the version of main project with 25 this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wiki which says it should exclude your library's AppCompat version something like this.

```
compile (project(":ATM-EditText")){
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

this will not ask your users to add tools attributes in manifest.