# Difference between compile(implementation) and include Project

Tags: java, android

Please let me know is there any difference between compile or implementation in dependency and include project. Are they matter on APK size or not?

Comment: Do you mean [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Comment: you can understand from @TentenPonce comment what differences are.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947897/gradle-dependencies-difference-between-compile-apk-project-compile-project-pro

Answer (score 0):

Yes it matter if you include library into your project it will increase the app size better to avoid include project into your existing project and implement implementation